# Can't test on my IPad - iOS version reported as too old

Tags: ios, xcode

My iPad2 device is running iOS 6.1. Since I upgraded XCode from 4.5->4.6 I get an error that my device is not running a new enough version of iOS!

[image]

I use no advanced features and in XCode my project iOS Deployment Target is 5.0.

Here are my settings:

[image][image]

Here are my provisioning stuff, it looks fine to me:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you can't install the iOS 6.0 SDK from within Xcode 4.6?

Comment: You should be able to set the deployment target to 6.0, I've got on app here (Xcode 4.6.3.) that targets iOS 4.3.

Comment: @trojanfoe I can't see any way to install sDK from within XCode, only Simulators.

Comment: @rckoenes No it's not listed. I have "iOS 6.1" and "Latest iOS (iOS 6.1)" only in the list "Base SDK"

Comment: You have to use the latest SDK, don't change that, but change the deployment target to 5.0, 6.0 or whatever you want. It's inside project and inside project info, and inside target summary, I think you have to change both of them

Comment: Sorry  I should have said I already see and selected the lower deployment targets and have 5.0 right now. But something else is clearly not right.

Comment: @john try removing your provisioning profiles from your ipad and hook up ipad2 to xcode. It should reinstall provision profiles again. This by no means a solution but a hunch. I am sure you have already done the usualy suspects, removed binary from ipad and clean build?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Xcode 4.6 and see I have all deployable targets available. See screenshots. Though note the base SDK is set to iOS 6.1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As I said, I am already setting deployment target as 5.0... but XCode says my device (iOS6.0) is running too old a version. So the SDK version should not be an issue, something else is to blame?

Comment: I honestly don't understand. See this project that I have, its deployable set to 5.0 - i too have an pad2 running iOS 6.0 and I am able to deploy to it just fine. There has to be some project settings that need to be tweaked

Comment: take a screenshot of the error you get from Xcode and paste it in your post

Comment: Good idea, I edited my question with this and my build settings.

Comment: @john try this - in your projects target's supported Device (under Targets -> APP_TARGET -> Summary -> Devices in the project settings) see if it is set to 'iPhone', when the app was supposed to be 'Universal' all along, and I you were trying to deploy to an iPad

Answer (score 0):

Apple always suggests building against the latest SDK and then setting the deployment target to whatever you want it to be. Also make sure any IB item has the correct deployment version set as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a helper for newer developers (like me):

I had problems testing my iPhone app on a new iPad and it was due to not running Organizer to initialising the new device (iPhone or iPad). 
(You also have to select that the device is used for debugging)

It will update your new device with the necessary libraries and then deploying is simple.

You can run Organizer from the Xcode->Windows menu.